# Some computers show "Windows can't communicate with the device or resource (primary DNS server)" but not all

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, router, dns, iphone

In the past few days I've run into an issue where the internet connection seems to drop out on a few devices at a time. This started Monday but has persisted despite appearing to be fixed a few times. I will often get the following message on an internet browser "Windows can't communicate with the device or resource (primary DNS server)". This issue also seems frequently affect 1-2 phone connections as well. Not all of the devices in my home experience this issue at the same time, and some seem to have more issues than others. There's also one computer that seems to be impervious to this issue.

One oddity I've seen is that affected computers tend to identify the network as "My Network Name" 2 instead of just "My Network Name". I don't know if that's indicative of anything or not, but seemed to be relevant.

I've tried the following on affect PCs, but none of it seems to resolve the problem and I'm not sure how to do resolve the issue on phones.

1. Simple reboots of both the router and affected devices
2. Resetting the TCP/IP stack as mentioned on several threads
3. Flushing and Registering the DNS tables on computers
4. Toggling WiFi connections on phones (sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't)

I'm not sure what else to try at this point. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the _impervious_ computer also connected by WiFi or by a cable? Also is it possible that another AP is in the vicinity (before answering NO, please run some app that shows available networks and their channel and vicinity, [like this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer))?

Comment: Both are connected via WiFi. There are also several other networks around from neigbors, but none that either computer would have previously been connected to. Our router also has a 2.4 and 5GHz channel. Both of which seem to drop out at times.

Comment: As suggested by @Kitet, it sounds very much like either you or a neighbor are running an identical SSID for your wireless network. It’s possible you have an ISP provided device with WiFi enabled and your own router with WiFi enabled using the same network name. Or this is a deliberate attempt to hijack your internet connection. You can use something like inSSIDer to see better details about nearby networks. You can also use various `netsh` commands to identify different BSSIDs using the same SSID. But I think it’s clear your devices are connecting to a “rogue” network intermittently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While troubleshooting some this morning I realized my wireless router and a new wired router I connected up this past weekend both defaulted to the same IP address. I was able to set a different static IP on the wired router and now everything appears to be working fine.